# Ошибка установки PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pip, install

При установке библиотеки *PyQt5*  для питона через:

```
pip3 install pyqt5
```

Выводит :

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-68853dge/pyqt5/

Что делать собственно? "Гугление" привело в сторону *PyNaCl*  но, собственно ни к чему толковому не привело.

Comment: Попробуйте просмотреть https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpyqt5%5D+python+setup.py+egg_info

Comment: Благодарю, первая выдача решила вопрос)))

Comment: Welcome to PyQt5